# Does the iOS settings schema secure text field use the key chain i.e. secure storage

Tags: ios, security

My app needs to have a very secure story and while I would like to use the standard iOS settings for my Apps settings I can not find anywhere whether or not the "secure text field" I would use for a password uses the key chain?

Comment: The docs are not clear on this. Most likely the text entered into the secure text field is simply stored as plain text in `NSUserDefaults` along with all of the other settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything what is in your Settings bundle is stored in NSUserDefaults. But the questions is why then some famous apps (e.g. Facebook) offer users to change their password in user defaults? Here's my thoughts how it works.

1. The password you see in Settings app is secure text field and the user is unable to read it or edit! He is able only to enter a new one!
2. You may perform the following algorithm:
   2.1 As the user types a password in Settings App you'll receive notification about it.
   2.2 You get this new password (check it if required) and save it in secure storage i.e in key chain or NSURLCredentials.
   2.3 You delete this password from NSUserDefaults. Actually you replace it with dummy text which contains the same number of characters. Then the user is unable to detect whether it is his password or dummy characters as they are secure.

You subscribe for notifications about NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(defaultsChanged:) name:NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

You Implement defaultsChanged: (That's I wrote on the fly...not tested)

```
- (void)defaultsChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
  // Get the user defaults
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = (NSUserDefaults *)[notification object];
  NSString *newPassword = [defaults objectForKey:@"YourPasswordKey"];

  // (Check new password if necessary) save it securely
  // Or store it securely and use it for authentication only when the User returns to your app again.

  NSString *dummyText = //The string the same length as newPassword containing e.g. only * character

  [defaults setObject:dummyText forKey:@"YourPasswordKey"];
}
```

Summary: you allow your user to enter a password in Settings app via Settings Bundle. But you store password securely. There will be only very short period of time when this sensitive information will be in User Defaults. The user won't know wether it's his password in Settings or not.

Note: if your app is not launched, it won't probably receive notifications until it will be launched. In this case you may read NSUserDefualts for new password value and replace on the app launch. Anyway it also won't be a long time as the user will probably launch your app shortly after he changed his password.

Regards.